# Android app link multiple intent filter hosts and manifest merge not working

Tags: android, android-intent, deep-linking

I am working with build variants and want to capture additional links based on the variant. I want all variants to capture links from host one so I have declared an `intent-filter` in my main `AndroidManifest.xml` file like so:

```
<activity android:name=".activity.DeepLinkActivity"
android:noHistory="true">
    <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

    <data android:host="hostOne.com" android:path="/page.aspx" android:scheme="http"/>

    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I am also generating a partial manifest for other variants such as hostTwo.com like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><manifest package="com.package.my.domain">
  <application xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:name="AlarmMobile">
    <activity android:name=".activity.DeepLinkActivity">
      <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:scheme="http://" android:host="hostTwo.com" android:path="/page.aspx"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

It is placed in an appropriately named folder according to the build variant [(based upon the documentation here)](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html) and Android studio's merged manifest view shows that the `intent-filter` for host two has been added to the final merged manifest, however, the emulator or actual device fails to capture intents meant for the second host.

I am generating intents like so in the command prompt:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -c android.intent.category.BROWSABLE -d "http://hostone.com/page.aspx"
```

which works for hostone, but doing

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -c android.intent.category.BROWSABLE -d "http://hosttwo.com/page.aspx"
```

will launch the browser because the app fails to capture it.

Do android app links only work for one host name? Is there anything else which I can try?

Comment: Check the generated AndroidManifest file (open apk file in Android Studio)

Comment: `host="hostOne.com"`
`host="hostTwo"`
Could this small difference be the problem?(You miss .com) In my case I'm using one intent-filter with two <data> for different hosts.

Comment: @Michael that was a mistake on my part when I was editing out the actual sites used :) If putting all of the data tags in one intent-filter declaration works I could fall back on doing that in the partial manifest but I'd rather not so I don't have to generate one for each flavor/variant combo

Comment: @SimonMarquis I checked the generated manifest by going to Build > Analyze apk and the definitions are as expected. The app fails to recognize the intents and the verifier statements never appear in the console for them. I tried putting all of the definitions in the generated manifest because I suspected having more than intent-filter with auto-verify="true" might have been the issue but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that the partial manifest was incorrect. In the `intent-filter`'s `data` tag, `android:scheme="http://"` is invalid due to the trailing `://`.

According to [google's documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#DataTest), Android builds the `intent-filter` URI like so: `<scheme>://<host>:<port>/<path>` so including it in the declaration is unnecessary.

After changing my declaration to `android:scheme="http"` the merge continues to be successful and the OS attempts to validate the links defined in the partial manifest!

Corrected partial manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><manifest package="com.package.my.domain">
  <application xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:name="AlarmMobile">
    <activity android:name=".activity.DeepLinkActivity">
      <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:scheme="http" android:host="hostTwo.com" android:path="/page.aspx"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```